When is the last day of my notice period after serving my reserve duty?
I've sent my resignation notice on the 23rd July 24 (Tuesday) which makes my last day to fall on the 23rd August 24 (Friday). But I have to serve my Singapore army reserve duty on the 6-8 August (Tuesday - Thursday). From what I understand from the MOM website, reserve duty doesn't count in the notice period and I need to serve an extra 3 days - but my last day is on a Friday. Do I need to serve the 3 days inclusive of the weekends which will end on the Monday (26th August) or need to serve on the working days which will end on Wednesday (28th August)?
My job is a 5 weekdays work every week with weekends off.

You need to tell us at least your country. Is "reservist" some kind of military service? Every country will have different rules for this.

I am not very familiar with workplace norms in Singapore, but from the same website you mentioned, I quote:

How to count start and end of notice period
The notice period includes:

The day on which notice is given.
Public holidays, rest days and non-working days.


and regarding "Reservist training",

Reservist training is not considered as part of the notice period. For example, if you go for 1 week of reservist training while serving notice, your notice period will be extended by 1 week.

So, following that logic, due to the 3-day Reservist training in between, your  last working day will be extended by 3 days, i.e., Aug 26 (including the weekends, as mentioned in the first quote).

But of course the company may have flexibility if you want something different, you should ask them.
